# Jupyter Notebook template or starting boilerplate?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I've been given the task to look for a method or automate a way to start a Jupyter notebook with a requirements.txt file passed trough some type of cli or command line argument, by doing my research it doesn't even seem to be a question people is asking, so either the answer must be too simple and I'm formulating it incorrectly or its just straight up not the way for these notebooks to be used.

If someone could give me some insights and some basic general idea of how to or why is not possible I'd appreciate it.

## EDIT

Some further explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish.
My vision is to run in my terminal

`$ cliname requirements.txt`

`...`

`installing packages..`

`Packages installed, starting server`

Which then will execute the necessary commands to create an environment ready to import the packages, do data science or any other activity a team usually does.

I'm not asking for the code, but more like asking the question if this behavior is possible, and if so a good approach to accomplish this.

Here is an example of the a standard python requirements.txt file that can be used with pip or other package managers.

```
attrs==19.3.0
boto3==1.10.7
botocore==1.13.7
Click==7.0
docutils==0.15.2
fire==0.2.1
flasgger==0.9.3
Flask==1.1.1
importlib-metadata==0.23
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
jmespath==0.9.4
joblib==0.14.0
jsonschema==2.6.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mistune==0.8.4
more-itertools==7.2.0
numpy==1.17.3
pandas==0.25.3
#pkg-resources==0.0.0
#pyrsistent==0.15.5
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-dotenv==0.10.3
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==5.1.2
s3transfer==0.2.1
scikit-learn==0.21.3
scipy==1.3.1
six==1.12.0
termcolor==1.1.0
urllib3==1.25.6
Werkzeug==0.16.0
xgboost==0.90
zipp==3.4.1
```

Comment: What do you mean by _passed through cli argument_? Do you want to provide a content of text file as an argument for python of a notebook? Perhaps you want to [make a custom kernel for jupyter](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kernels.html)?

Comment: Correct, and example of the behavior I want is ```cliname requirements.txt``` and boom, notebook started with all your dependencies.

Comment: I see what you want to do. But elaborating (by updating your question) further about what you want to do actually (import some predefined modules automatically?) with what file content (a text file with what? names of modules?) with a vivid example would help both of us ;)

Comment: Understood, I'm not trying to import the packages from the get go, essentially just creating an environment. I submitted an edit anyways trying to expand better on what I want, thanks!.

Comment: Thanks for the edit; I've voted to reopen it. But you can report the question with the edited contents if you don't want to wait for the vote to take place